# Fetching a user by username

Tags: apex, api, user

I have written an api to fetch a user by using the username. The funny behavior is that when I use the following query, it doesn't return any results:

```
List<User> ul = [Select Id, Username FROM User WHERE Username =:username];
```

But when I change the `Username` to `Id` and pass the Id (without changing anything else), it gives the results.

```
List<User> ul = [Select Id, Username FROM User WHERE Id =:id];
```

What is happening and how can I use the username to get the user details?

Note: When I run both the commands in query editor, they give the desired results.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, the cause was an unfortunate test data, I was using a username with a "+1" in the middle and when the request param is obtained, the "+1" had been converted to a space, causing a different username.

If I used the following request with `something+1@email.com` as the username:

```
https://someapp.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/test?username=something+1@email.com
```

And the Apex code was:

```
    @HttpGet
    global static void get() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        try {
            String username = req.params.get('username');
            System.debug(username);
            //The username printed above is: something @email.com
            //Note the "+1" is missing

            User u = fetchUser(username);
            //set response
        } 
        catch(BadRequestException e) {
            //handle error
        }
    }
```

In the printed log the "+1" would be missing. How can I preserve it?

Comment: What are you passing in for a username? It should be something like "derek.f@comany.tld" as opposed to, say, "derek f"

Comment: Yes it was in the expected format

Comment: try using Sting.valueOf(req.params.get('username');?

Comment: wait... it is URL encoding, you need to replace the "+" with "%2B"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP "+" is url encoding for "space" String.valueOf might work, but if that still pulls the decoded value for "+" then you may need to use "%2B" for plus signs.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the URL

```
https://someapp.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/test?username=something+1@email.com
```

`+` is treated as a space

you need to provide the URL to look like:

```
https://someapp.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/test?username=something%2B1@email.com
```

where [2B is the encoding for a `+`](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just a random thought while I dig into it a bit more...

Try to make your argument/param name something different than username, like "myUserName" or something.

I have run into issues before where because the param name is the same as something else special in the framework, weird stuff happens.

UPDATE:

I just ran your exact code in my anon apex vs my own and both print the same thing:

```
 String username = 'test@salesforce.com';
List<User> myUser = [SELECT Id, Username FROM User WHERE Username =:username];

system.debug(myUser);

List<User> ul = [Select Id, Username FROM User WHERE Username =:username];

system.debug(ul);
```

Both statements printed the same info, so it should work. Can you provide the apex that is setting the bind variable as well?

**UPDATE**

Try using String.valueof to retrieve the param as seen [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333303&type=1&mode=1)

Like this: `String username = String.valueOf(req.params.get('username'));`

**FINAL UPDATE**

I read this wrong... it is URL Encoding, you need to replace the "+" with "%2B"

Comment: I've updated the problem. Apparently the cause was the existence of "+1" in the username. So now the question is, how to preserve special characters?

Comment: I updated my answer